# WordPress: get_page_children of an existing page's ID returning empty array

Tags: wordpress

The page whose ID equals 7 is defined as being the parent of 2 pages (done in back-office).

I created this shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('display_children_pages', function($params) {
    $html_to_display = '';
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump(get_the_ID());
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump(get_page_children(get_the_ID()));
    echo "</pre>";
    return $html_to_display;
});
```

Which echos:

> get_the_ID(): int(7)

and

> get_page_children(get_the_ID()): array(0) []

Why does this call to `get_page_children` return an empty array instead of an array of page #7's children pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the second required argument in [get_page_children()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children) - check out the documentation, but basically, that function *filters* the passed in list of pages, it doesn't make a query to the DB to "find" children pages.  For that, your best bet is to use [get_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages):

```
  $args = array(
      'parent'      => get_the_ID(),
      'post_type'   => 'page',
      'post_status' => 'publish'
  ); 

  $pages = get_pages( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code will return all child pages

```
 add_shortcode('display_children_pages', function($params) {
            $html_to_display = '';
            echo "<pre>";var_dump(get_the_ID());echo "</pre>";


        $args = array(
          'post_parent'     => get_the_ID(),
          'post_type'       => 'shop_subscription'
        );

        $child = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($child->have_posts()) : while ($child->have_posts()) : $child->the_post();
          $childids[] = get_the_id();  
        endwhile;
        else:
          $childids[] = "not set";
        endif;
         echo "<pre>";var_dump($childids);echo "</pre>";
            return $childids;
});
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but this answer is _not helpful_: 1. What did you change?  Why does this work where OP's original code doesn't?  2. Your code is a formatting mess - maybe consider formatting it better, 3. Why are you using "template-style" `if` and `while` statements, rather than "standard" `if ($condition) {`....  4. WP functions are case-sensitive.  For example, it's `get_the_ID()`, _not_ `get_the_id()`...